# Google cloud Bucket access

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I have to access the data in google clound bucket to my VM instance (jupyter notebook). I got this error and also getting problems related to this.

ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 2.7.x.
If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

The Google cloud SDK is not compatible with Python3 for now. You will have to default to a better version as such 2.7.9 or later to work with the SDK.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How it can be changed to 2.7.9 in Google VM instance. I am struggling to upload the dataset from internet to VM instance for that i have uploaded the dataset on cloud storage bucket but the command to transfer the data from bucket to intance is not working and it was showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

@Raunak Jhawar I have configured an initialization action script that allow to use python 3.

```
#!/bin/bash
# from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nehalecky/9258c01fb2077f51545a/raw/789f08141dc681cf1ad5da05455c2cd01d1649e8/install-py3-dataproc.sh

apt-get -y install python3
echo "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3" | tee -a  /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh  /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
echo "Adding PYTHONHASHSEED=0 to profiles and spark-defaults.conf..."
echo "export PYTHONHASHSEED=0" | tee -a /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
echo "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0" >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

The issue is irrelevant to python 3